# "Call to a member function active_pest() on array" when using SyncWithoutDetaching() to update a pivot table

Tags: eloquent

I'm trying to using SyncWithoutDetaching() to update a pivot table (active_pest) but am getting a "Call to a member function active_pest() on array" error message.

The background here is that I have 8 tables: products, pests, actives (i.e active ingredients), crops, active_product, pest_product, crop_product, and active_pest.  My form collects information about a selected (agrichemical) product - in that form, the user selects the pests, actives, and crops associated with that product. When submitted, my existing code is saving the expected information in the products table and, through a set of "belongsToMany" relationships, the active_product, pest_product, and crop_product pivot tables are also correctly updated.

For any given product there are typically 1 or 2 actives and 3-8 pests and it is those id values that I want to add to the active_pest pivot table.

My code is:

```
// ProductController

public function update(UpdateRequest $request)
{
  $actives = $request->get('active');
  $actives->active_pest()->SyncWithoutDetaching( $request->get('pest'));

...

}

// pest model
public function active_pest()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Pest', 'active_pest', 'active_id', 'pest_id');
}
```

Answers to other questions about this type of error message indicate that there is something wrong with the active_pest() relationship - but I got the same error message after making a typo there (active_pestr). Regardless, I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Insight appreciated. Thanks, Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$actives = $request->get('active');
```

Just return array, so you are trying something like this [1,2,3]->active_pest().

Which is exactly what it says. Call to a member function active_pest() on array.

You need to work with eloquent instance to perform `->active_pest()->SyncWithoutDetaching( $request->get('pest'));`

So you can find you instances like this:

```
$actives = Active::whereIn('col_name', $request->get('active'))->get();
```

This will return you collection of instances, to save pest for each of them you need to iterate with foreach like this:

```
foreach($actives as $active){
    $active->active_pest()->SyncWithoutDetaching( $request->get('pest'));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation as well as the code - I'm off merrily rejoicing. Tom.